# Shell Script For Printing in Multiple Printers

Tags: shell

I have a below shell script which checks an email account and automatically prints the attachment to the printer listed on line 8 in the script. Could you please help me to modify it so that line 8 is a variable and the variable can be set by inserting the appropriate text PRINTER=FOO into the body of the email. This will allow for the script to print to multiple printers.

```
#!/bin/bash
#while [ 1 ]
while [ 1 ]
do
SUPPORTED_FILETYPES=".pdf"
#LP_OPTIONS="-o media=A4,tray1 -o fit-to-page -o position=top -o scaling=100"
LP_OPTIONS=""
PRINTER="PRT04-3" #line no. 8 

MAILFILE=~/eprint/$(date +%H%M%S).txt

PRINT_FOLDER=~/eprint/printable
/usr/bin/fetchmail --bsmtp $MAILFILE

if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
   MAIL_ADDRESS=$(grep 'From:' $MAILFILE | sed -n -e 's/^[^<]*<\([^>]*\)>.*$/\1/p')
   /usr/bin/uudeview +e $SUPPORTED_FILETYPES -p $PRINT_FOLDER -i $MAILFILE
   rm $MAILFILE

   PRINTED="no"

   for f in $PRINT_FOLDER/*

   do
      if [ "$f" != "$PRINT_FOLDER/*" ]; then
         LP_OUTPUT=$(lp $LP_OPTIONS "$f" -d $PRINTER)
         if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
            MAILTEXT="File "$f" could not be printed."
            echo "$MAILTEXT" | mail -s "Print-Error" $MAIL_ADDRESS
         fi
         rm "$f"
         PRINTED="yes"
      else
         if [ "$PRINTED" = "no" ]; then
            echo "No printable Attachments" | mail -s "Print-Error" $MAIL_ADDRESS
         fi
      fi
   done
  # ~/mailprint
fi
sleep 4
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you limit PRINTER=FOO to its own line, that will be easy:

```
PRINTERLINE=$(grep 'PRINTER=' $MAILFILE)
eval $PRINTERLINE #eval PRINTER=FOO
#$PRINTER equals to FOO now
```